# Error removing location huawei kit android studio

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-location-kit

I am following this tutorial about location kit inside a fragment ->
[tutorial](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSLocationKit/index.html#5)

All is good, the only thing that I change is that I call the method `removeLocationUpdatesWithCallback()` inside the method `location_initialize()`. The first time the location removes but when I change the fragment and I return the `removeLocationUpdatesWithCallback()` does not work and I get on failure message:

> 10804 no_matched_callback

This is my code:

```java
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());
    settingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(getActivity());
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(500);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    location_initialize();
    requestLocationUpdatesWithCallback();   
}


private void location_initialize(){
    if (null == mLocationCallback) {
        mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                img_user = Constants.img_url+Constants.GetLbd(getActivity(), "img_user");
                if (locationResult != null) {
                    List<Location> locations = locationResult.getLocations();
                    if (!locations.isEmpty()) {
                        for (Location location : locations) {
                            usr_posicion = location;
                            CiudadCercana(location);
                        }
                    }
                }
                todasSucursales_func();
                removeLocationUpdatesWithCallback();
            }
            @Override
            public void onLocationAvailability(LocationAvailability locationAvailability) {
                if (locationAvailability != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Geolocalización no disponible por el momento", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        };
    }
}

public void requestLocationUpdatesWithCallback() {
    try {
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
        builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        LocationSettingsRequest locationSettingsRequest = builder.build();
        // check devices settings before request location updates.
        settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(locationSettingsRequest)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
                        //check location settings success
                        //request location updates
                        fusedLocationProviderClient
                                .requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper())
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                        //"requestLocationUpdatesWithCallback onSuccess"
                                    }
                                })
                                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                                        //"requestLocationUpdatesWithCallback onFailure:"
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                        //"checkLocationSetting onFailure:"
                        int statusCode = ((ApiException) e).getStatusCode();
                        switch (statusCode) {
                            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                                try {
                                    ResolvableApiException rae = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                                    rae.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), 0);
                                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sie) {
                                    //"PendingIntent unable to execute request."
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //"requestLocationUpdatesWithCallback exception:"
    }
}

private void removeLocationUpdatesWithCallback() {
    try {
        fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "removeLocationUpdatesWithCallback onSuccess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //"removeLocationUpdatesWithCallback onSuccess"
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                        ->>>>>>HERE IS MY ERROR<<<<<--
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "removeLocationUpdatesWithCallback onFailure:" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //"removeLocationUpdatesWithCallback onFailure:" + e.getMessage()
                    }
                });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "removeLocationUpdatesWithCallback exception:" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //"removeLocationUpdatesWithCallback exception:" + e.getMessage()
    }
}
```

How can I solve that, only the `removeLocationUpdatesWithCallback()` method fails :(

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, please remove the line

```
        removeLocationUpdatesWithCallback();
```

from the method

```
                  private void location_initialize(){
```

And call the function
removeLocationUpdatesWithCallback()

in other place such as onClick of a view component or onDestroy() of the Activity or Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check the Device Location Settings. The location function of Location Kit depends on the device location settings. For example, if the location function is disabled on a device, your app cannot obtain the device location. Therefore, it is recommended that your app check whether the device settings meet the location requirements before continuously obtaining the device location. Location Kit provides the function of checking device location settings. Your app can obtain the [SettingsClient](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/HMSCore-References-V5/settingsclient-0000001051066118-V5?ha_source=hms1) instance using [getSettingsClient](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/HMSCore-References-V5/locationservice-0000001050746175-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001053450609__section1742582817364?ha_source=hms1)**(Activity activity)** of [LocationServices](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/HMSCore-References-V5/locationservice-0000001050746175-V5?ha_source=hms1) and call the [checkLocationSettings](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/HMSCore-References-V5/settingsclient-0000001051066118-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001054289302__section1653772245611?ha_source=hms1)**(LocationSettingsRequest locationSettingsRequest)** API to obtain the device location settings. If the location settings do not meet the requirements, your app can prompt users to grant related permissions. The location permission must be granted to HMS Core (APK). In Android Q, **Location** must be set to **Always** for HMS Core (APK).
2. The description of *NO_MATCHED_CALLBACK* is *No matched callback*. Please verify that the correct callback has been passed to the parameter list.

For more information, see [docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/location-develop-steps-0000001050746143-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001053849291__section27456713112?ha_source=hms1).